# Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '([AnyObject],(_) -> _)'

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7

I write one method in swift 1 like this :

```
public var array: [JSON]? {
     get {
         if self.type == .Array {
             return map(self.object as! [AnyObject]){ JSON($0) }
         } else {
             return nil
         }
     }
}
```

when I install Xcode 7.2 (swift 2) this method give me error like this :

**Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '([AnyObject],(_) -> _)'**

now I want to know what is that problem?

Comment: Try return (self.object as! [AnyObject]).map { JSON($0) }

Comment: @RamkrishnaSharma are you sure right this?

Comment: Please look into the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673694/swift-2-0-cannot-invoke-map-with-argumet-list-of-type-anyobject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use forced cast, and call `map` on the array, as the function was moved in Swift 2

```
return (self.object as? [AnyObject])?.map{ JSON($0) }
```